# $p$-torsion of an abelian variety of $p$-rank $0$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties, formal-groups, positive-characteristic

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic $p > 0$ and let $A$ be an abelian variety over $k$ such that $A[p](k) = 0$, i.e., such that $A$ has $p$-rank $0$. If I am not mistaken, this implies that $\mathrm{Ker}(F) \subset A[p]$, where $\mathrm{Ker}(F)$ is the Frobenius kernel of $A$. Is it true that $A[p] = \mathrm{Ker}(F^2)$, i.e., that $A[p]$ is the $p^2$-Frobenius kernel of $A$? Equivalently, is $I^{p^2} = 0$, where $I$ denotes the augmentation ideal of $A[p]$?

I know that the claim is true for elliptic curves but am confused about the higher dimensional case...

Comment: This question was answered a while ago but I just wanted to add that the way I would get a feeling for this problem (and then quickly realise that your hope was false) would be to look at the Dieudonne module of the p-divisible group; one can now write down explicit abstract Dieudonne modules where this fails, realise the situation is more subtle, and then try and realise them as DMs of AVs as is done in the answers below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, this is another entry in the list of ways in which elliptic curves can be a poor guide to the higher-dimensional case. The kernel of $F_{A/k}:A \rightarrow A^{(p)}$ is *always* contained in $A[p]$ since $\ker F_{A/k}$ is an infinitesimal commutative group scheme whose own Frobenius morphism vanishes (and all such are killed by $p$).   The $p$-rank being 0 expresses that the slopes of the Dieudonne module of the $p$-divisible group are all positive.

In general $F_{A/k}$ is an isogeny of degree $p^g$ for $g = \dim A$, so $F^2$ is an isogeny of degree $p^{2g}$.  Strictly speaking, we really mean the 2-fold Frobenius isogeny $F_{A/k,2}$, since it doesn't literally make sense to compose $F_{A/k}$ with itself (as its source and target are not "the same"). Thus, $A[p] = \ker(F_{A/k,2})$ if and only if either of these is contained in the other, or equivalently $[p]$ factors through $F_{A/k,2}$ via an isomorphism, or vice-versa, so it amounts to saying that the Frobenius slopes of the Dieudonne module of $A[p^{\infty}]$ are *all* equal to 1/2; i.e., it is "isoclinic" of slope 1/2 (and rank $2g$).

For elliptic curves, if both slopes are positive then they are forced to be 1/2 and the elliptic curve is forced to be supersingular.  But in higher dimensions Honda-Tate theory provides many absolutely simple abelian varieties over finite fields whose slopes are positive but not all equal to 1/2 (by constructing appropriate Weil numbers), and then passing up to $k$ gives counterexamples. See 2.3.5 in the book "Complex multiplication and lifting problems" for one concrete supply of such examples (which have some additional interesting features), but there is a vast array of many more.

Answer (score 2):

An explicit example is the Jacobian of the hyperelliptic genus-$3$ curve in characteristic two, $Y^2+Y=X^7$. The vertices of the polygon are $(0,0)$, $(3,1)$, and $(6,3)$, giving slopes of $1/3$ and $2/3$.